# HtmlHelpers for managing scripts for Razor Partial Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I'm trying to use [Forloop HtmlHelpers](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Forloop.HtmlHelpers/) for managing scripts for Razor Partial Views in my ASP.Net MVC 4 project.

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
  //some markups here
 </div>

 @{
  // begin a context for the scripts
   Html.BeginScriptContext();

   Html.AddScriptBlock(@"$(function() { alert('hello from the page'); } });");
   Html.AddScriptFile("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js");

   // end the script context
   Html.EndScriptContext();
   }
```

But, it's throwing the following error during compile -

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for
>   'BeginScriptContext' and no extension method 'BeginScriptContext'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've installed this package via package manager console.
How to overcome this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `Forloop.HtmlHelpers` namespace

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="BaseTemplate.Web.Extensions.BaseTemplateWebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <! -- Add the following namespace to the others -->
        <add namespace="Forloop.HtmlHelpers" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

to the `Web.config` within the `Views` folder in your application.

<strike>A future update of the nuget package will add this for you. In the meantime, [I have updated the wiki page with this information](https://bitbucket.org/forloop/forloop-htmlhelpers/wiki/Home) :)</strike>

**EDIT : This is now performed as part of the nuget package installation.**

Also, I would recommend using the following syntax as it's a little more terse

```
@using (Html.BeginScriptContext())
{
    Html.AddScriptBlock(
       @<script type="text/javascript">
           $(function() { alert('hello from the page'); } });
       </script>);
    Html.AddScriptFile("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js");
}
```