# How to include js file only if it is used

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an editor template that requires a specific js library to be included. I want it to be included only if this editor is used on a page, and I want to include it only once, no matter how many editors are used. How can I do that?

*Update*

I have found this post: [HtmlHelpers for managing scripts for Razor Partial Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19685045/htmlhelpers-for-managing-scripts-for-razor-partial-views) which does something like I want (no idea how I missed it in the first place). Unfortunately the library I want to include comes with css, which this answer does not support

Comment: What is the logic you are using to detect if editor is used on page - you could just use that to create a script section - `@section scripts{ ... }`

Comment: @JamesP I do not detect. I could I guess, but that doesn't sound very intuitive.

Comment: Could you elaborate as its not very clear what you want from the original question.

Comment: @JamesP I have an editor (and I think it is a partial view, so I cannot use `@section scripts`), and it uses a separate library that is a bundle of js + css. I want this editor to include these scripts in the project, but I do not want to be included in the page all the times, as the editor is used rarely.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to what Facebook does. In your widget, you can dynamically load library by adding code similar to following which at runtime adds a script tag and attempts to load your script file. If component isn't rendering, script won't load too.

```
<script>  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This might work, but I cannot say I like the solution. Also I'm not sure I can do that for css.